# how to embedded javascript in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

i am developing an application for login page for linkedIn. so here i know how to log in through java script.but i dont know how to embedded javascript in my application plz help me

Answer (score 1):

`1 -` Check your Blackberry device OS version before you begin. You can accomplish this step by clicking on the "Options" link and then clicking on "About." You will need to be using Blackberry OS 4.0 or higher; older versions do not support JavaScript.

`2-` Open your Blackberry Internet Browser by clicking on your "Internet" icon on the home screen of your Blackberry.

`3-` Click on the "Options" link in the Blackberry Internet browser.

`4-` Choose the "Browser Configuration" option. Scroll down through the choices shown and click on the option that says "Support JavaScript."

`5-` Choose "Enable" for "Support JavaScript," which will turn on JavaScript for your Internet browser.

`6-` Choose the "Save" option. Now simply browse to a web page with JavaScript enabled to test your newly installed setting.

`After that` create this code to test if it's working :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 <!--hide

  var password;
  var numberOfAttempts = 3;

  password=prompt('Please enter the password to access this page page!',' ');

  if(password > 999 && password < 4001)
  {
       {
       alert('Password Correct! Click OK to enter!');
       window.location="http://www.celticfc.net...";
       }

  }
  do
  {
       password=prompt('Please enter the password to access this page page!',' ');
       numberOfAttempts++;
  }
  while(password <= 999 && password >= 4001)
  {
       alert('Password Incorrect! Click OK to try again!');
  }
```

Comment: write in a javascirpt file like 'myApp.js' and upload it to your BB.